# Created folder is not visible in the sdcard folder

Tags: android

I want to create the pictures folder and in that i want to add flower.png image  in the sdcard.

I have 2 buttons in my layout file one is  save and load when I click on save button its must save in the sd card.With the below code,Its displaying a toast message “data written successfully". But I can't see the created folder and file on the sdcard in file explorer. only sd card folder is visible to me.when I click on load button it must gather the saved image from sdcard and set in the image view.But here also im getting only toast message “data written successfully in the image view.But the imageview with loaded images is not displaying can any body help me ?

This is may layout file:
    **main.xml**

This is my activity file:

```
public class AndroidExternalStorageActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnSave,btnLoad;
    Bitmap bmp;
    String s;
    InputStream inputstream;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        btnLoad = (Button)findViewById(R.id.load);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);  
        btnLoad.setOnClickListener(this);       
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.save)
        {



                 s=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if(s.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                {
                    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File f = new File(root+ "/pictures/", "logos.png");
                    f.mkdir();



                    try {
                        //fis = new FileInputStream(R.drawable.logos);
                        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("logo.jpg");
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                        try
                 {
                   FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);


                   int read = 0;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    while ((read = inputstream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
                    }
                   fos.flush();
                   fos.close();


                   } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());

                   }
                   //DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);
                   //dos.writeBytes("Hello friends how are you,welcome to android session");
                   Toast.makeText(this,"Data Written successfully.." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();






    }
        }       

    else if(v.getId()==R.id.load)
    {
                        String s1=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                        if(s1.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                             File root1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                             File f1 = new File(root1 + "/pictures/", "logos.png");
                             ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                                Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/pictures/logos.png");
                                iv.setEnabled(true);
                                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);


                             Toast.makeText(this, "image is uploaded successfully in imageview" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             //dis.close();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println(e);

                        }
                    }


        }
    }
            }




 I also added the following permissions in my manifest file:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">

    </uses-permission>

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">

     </uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create directory and file separately.

```
File directory = new File(root, "pictures");
directory.mkDirs();
File f = new File(directory, "logos.png");
f.createNewFile();
```

You can also get directory like this

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory("pictures");
directory.mkDirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the Previleges in `AndroidManiFest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This will provide you complete access to write onto your sdCard on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `save` button `onClick` option as follows:

1. First create `Folder Directory` then create `File`
2. There has a typo, at first you are creating `InputStream` object named `inputstream` but you are creating another `InputStream` object named `inputStream` where `S` is capital. You should not create it second time.

Compare and update your code with the following updated code snippet, I think you will get your problem solved.

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.save) {

    s = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (s.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File fileDir = new File(root.getAbsoluteFile() + "/pictures/");
        fileDir.mkdir();
        File f = new File(fileDir, "logos.png");

        try {
            inputstream = getAssets().open("logo.jpg");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = inputstream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Written successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry @Hamid i didnt get you. Ill surely accept your answer but im not getting the procedure can you explain me clearly?

Comment: I have already explained those facts which should be resolved.